# What is $\lim_{n \rightarrow\infty} \phi(T^{n}v)$

Tags: linear-algebra

I would please like to check my thinking on solving this problem:

> > $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space, and $T\in \mathcal L(V)$ is diagonalizable with all eigenvalues of $T$ less than one in absolute value. Given $\phi \in V'$ ($V'$ is the dual of $V$) and $v\in V$, what is $\lim_{n \rightarrow\infty} \phi(T^{n}v)$?

Since $T$ is diagonalizable, it can be represented as a matrix with the eigenvalues on the diagonal and zeros elsewhere. $T^{n}$ then would have the eigenvalues raised to the $n$th power on the diagonals. And since their absolute vales are less than one, as $n$ goes to infinity, the diagonal elements would go to zero. Thus $T$ becomes the zero operator.

Assuming this is correct, then I don't understand the reason the problem is phrased in the context of the dual operator, $\phi$ on $T^{n}v$

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T$ will never become the zero operator because it is NOT the zero operator in the first place. Also, $\phi$ being a linear form on $V$ will map vectors onto scalars. Therefore it makes perfect sense to define $\phi(T^nv)$. As you said, becomes all the eigenvalues of $T$ are less than one in absolute value, it is clear that $\lim_n \|T^nv\|=0$, and therefore $\lim_n\phi(T^nv)=0$.

Comment: Thanks. I think you meant all the eigenvalues of $T$, rather than $\phi$? I didn't mean to imply $\phi(\dot)$ did not make sense. But I think I am then missing how you get from $\lim_n \|T^nv\|=0$ to $\lim_n\phi(T^nv)=0$, in that it seems you are not taking $\lim_n\phi(0)=0$, as I incorrectly assumed.

Comment: Since $V$ is finite dimensional $\phi$ is continuous, and therefore $\lim_n\phi(v_n)=\phi(v)$, where $v=\lim_nv_n$.